# In unity dots physics,is there any way to scale mesh collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-dots

In traditional physics engine,we can scale the mesh collider by changing the scale in Transform property.
What about in dots physics,I've tried adding the scale property but it doesn't work.

In traditional physics engine,we can scale the mesh collider by changing the scale in Transform property.
What about in dots physics,I've tried adding the scale property but it doesn't work.